# Getting issue in codeigniter URL routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm working on a project where I need to create clean URL for every products, see following pattern:-

> **example.com/Single_Product_Page**

The original URL is **example.com/browse/Single_Product_Page** and I used following code:-

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'Products/browse/$1';
```

> I've two page **(1) example.com/Product** 
>   and **(2) example.com/Products/Single_Product_Page**

> > And it is working fine but now I'm unable to open **Products** page and when I tried to open it, It open **Single_Product_Page**

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your routes similar to this example (which works OK on my site):

```
$route['products'] = 'controller/myfunction/argument';
$route['products/:any'] = 'controller/myfunction/another_argument/$1/1';
```

you can get more insight from the docs [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#examples)

Comment: I don't want URL like example.com/Products/Single_Product_Page but I need clean URL like **example.com/Single_Product_Page**.

Comment: this is not quite standard and you will loose SEO friendliness, if all your products show in the single_product_page (instead of "single_product_page/redshirt" and  "single_product_page/greenshirt"; anyway you could achieve this with loading ajax content into that page

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little hack to use just your controller name (and that's a must of course) but eliminate the need to write the method name and pass your parameters directly after the controller name so basically your url would look like this: `http://localhost/controller/parameter` and that would give you shorter urls as you intend but not an SEO friendly as you claimed.

You can use `_remap` in your controller and check if it matched a method process it normally or pass it to your index (which is your default method that's doesn't have to be written in your url) .. and now you won't need to use index in your url as you intended.

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method === 'some_method_in_your_controller')
    {
            $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
            $this->index($method);
    }
}
```

Or you can depend on ajax for all of your crud operations and your url will be pretty much fixed all the time.